# getting unwanted errors on phpmyadmin php v8.0.11

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I am getting below error while accessing phpmyadmin from localhost/phpmyadmin

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpMyAdmin\Config\Forms\User\UserFormList" not found in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\UserPreferences.php:48 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Config\PageSettings.php(75): PhpMyAdmin\UserPreferences->pageInit(Object(PhpMyAdmin\Config\ConfigFile)) #1 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Navigation\Navigation.php(106): PhpMyAdmin\Config\PageSettings->_*construct('Navi', 'pma_navigation*...') #2 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Header.php(432): PhpMyAdmin\Navigation\Navigation->getDisplay() #3 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(331): PhpMyAdmin\Header->getDisplay() #4 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(345): PhpMyAdmin\Response->getDisplay() #5 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Response.php(507): PhpMyAdmin\Response->htmlResponse() #6 [internal function]: PhpMyAdmin\Response->response() #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\UserPreferences.php on line 48

Comment: Did you try updating phpMyAdmin to the latest version or use a different package altogether?

Comment: This looks like you have a broken installation of phpMyAdmin. It might be because you manually installed it and forgot to clear the route cache or something similar. Remove the whole installation and install again.